# Differences between polygon and polyline

Tags: svg

What is the difference between Polygon and Polyline in SVG? I replaced all the dots in those 2 samples and the results were exactly the same (in Google Chrome):

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=html5-17.htm
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=html5-18.htm

Is it just semantic difference without any actual result?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1"
```

to both examples , instead of

```
 fill="red"
```

and you'll see difference.

Polyline doesn't connect last point to first ! Polygon - always connects last point to the first. Problem was, that line color and fill color were the same.